# Display custom tax total row based on user roles in WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I'm building a webshop in WooCommerce and I need to show correct taxes in the order emails. I have 2 different user roles: "private" and "business"

The following code does the tax calculation and adds it to a new line. However, I need the output to be 0DKK for "business" user role *(since the price they pay is excl. tax)*:

```
// Add total taxes as a separated line before order total on orders and emails
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'insert_custom_line_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function insert_custom_line_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // Display only the gran total amount
    $gran_total = (float) $order->get_total();
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $total_html : strip_tags( $total_html );

    // Custom tax calculation (for 20% tax rate)
    $total_tax_amount = wc_price(  $gran_total - $gran_total / 1.25 );
    $total_tax_amount = is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $total_tax_amount : strip_tags( $total_tax_amount );

    // Create a new row for total tax
    $tax_row = array( 'order_tax_total' => array(
        'label' => __('Moms udgør:','woocommerce'),
        'value' => $total_tax_amount
    ) );

    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = wc_price( $gran_total );

    return $total_rows + $tax_row;
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will change your custom total tax row to zero for "business" user role:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'insert_custom_line_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function insert_custom_line_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $user  = $order->get_user(); // Gets WP_User Object from order
    $total = $order->get_total(); // Gets order grand total. incl. taxes

    // Clean total row displayed taxes
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = is_wc_endpoint_url() ? wc_price($total) : strip_tags(wc_price($total));

    // Get total tax formatted from a defined tax rate based on user roles
    $total_tax = in_array('business', $user->roles) ? wc_price(0) : wc_price($total - ($total / 1.25));

    // Insert total tax row
    $total_rows['order_tax_total'] = array(
        'label' => __('Moms udgør:','woocommerce'),
        'value' => is_wc_endpoint_url() ? $total_tax : strip_tags($total_tax),
    );

    return $total_rows;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Sure thing :) Thanks again!